# I want to checkout for a service (not a product) in my magento site

Tags: checkout

I want a customer to pay for a service (not a product). I have a service on a CMS page and if customer wants a detail description for the service then payment is required.

For this I had a button (say, Pay Now). If customer click on it then he/she should be redirected to checkout page for further process.

As I want to checkout for a service and not for a product so is this possible ?

If YES, How can I implement this ?

Comment: You can simply create virtual product instead of having in CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Same work I have also done in Magento 1.9. I have to create hospital Nursing services in Magento. For this, i have created a custom module where I created controller function to create order.

But this was done in single page i.e service selection, delivery address and payment was done on a single page and using ajax I used to post order details to that controller and create order.